# What is the purpose of void this in the javascript function

Tags: javascript, node.js

What is the purpose of `void this` in the javascript function `end`

```
words = ''; wordless=' ';

function say_it(word) {
     return word ? smothered_mouthfuls(word) : end();
}

function smothered_mouthfuls(word) {
    word = words ? wordless + word : word;
    words = words + word;
    return say_it;
 }

 function end() {
     return  void this,words;
 }
```

Any one know `void this` purpose, Thanks.

Comment: i don,t think it is for some test case, no big use in typing return void,value;

Answer (score 1):

What you have is the [`void`operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void)

> The **`void` operator** evaluates the given *`expression`* and then returns [undefined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined).

in combination with [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)

> The **comma operator** evaluates each of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the last operand.

```
return void this, words;
```

works like this

```
return (void this, words); // return words
```

Actually, it looks like noise to the code, without some meaning of the expression of `this`.

If the call of `this` invokes something, then it's necessary, otherwise it looks like *code smell*, where some code is doing something without explicit mention.

```js
var words = '', wordless=' ';

function say_it(word) {
    return word ? smothered_mouthfuls(word) : end();
}

function smothered_mouthfuls(word) {
    word = words ? wordless + word : word;
    words = words + word;
    return say_it;
}

function end() {
    void this;     // or not
    return  words;
}
   
console.log(say_it('foo')());
console.log(say_it('bar')());
console.log(say_it('baz')());
```